# Assembly Language 8086 add using 32 bit reg & give value in 64bit?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I want to **add** value1 to value2 by using 32bit register and give the value under 64bit(equals to 16 digits). Is it possible to use the space of 2 registers (32+32 = 64bit)? I think it can be done by using **PTR**  **OPERATOR** but I don't know how to use PTR Instruction.

I have made the program for addition. It takes two values in console and gives us the result. It can only take a value under **32 bits(8 digits)**. If we give a higher value then it will give an error of integer overflow in console.

I am using KIP.R.IRVINE Link Libraries in Assembly Language

How we will give a 64bit value by using 32bit registers? How do we enable 32bit registers to take a 64bit value?

Here is the code for the 32-bit addition

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

Addition BYTE "A: Add two Integer Numbers", 0

inputValue1st BYTE "Input the 1st integer = ",0
inputValue2nd BYTE "Input the 2nd integer = ",0

 outputSumMsg BYTE "The sum of the two integers is = ",0

 num1 DD ?
 num2 DD ?
 sum  DD ?

 .code

 main PROC

;----Displays addition Text-----

mov edx, OFFSET Addition
call WriteString
call Crlf
;-------------------------------

; calling procedures here

call InputValues
call addValue
call outputValue

call Crlf

jmp exitLabel


main ENDP


; the PROCEDURES which i have made is here


InputValues PROC
;----------- For 1st Value--------


call Crlf
mov edx,OFFSET inputValue1st ; input text1
call WriteString

; here it is taking 1st value
call ReadInt    ; read integer
mov num1, eax   ; store the value




;-----------For 2nd Value----------



mov edx,OFFSET inputValue2nd ; input text2
call WriteString


; here it is taking 2nd value
call ReadInt    ; read integer
mov num2, eax   ; store the value

ret
InputValues ENDP




;---------Adding Sum----------------

addValue PROC
; compute the sum

mov eax, num2  ; moves num2 to eax
add eax, num1  ; adds num2 to num1
mov sum, eax   ; the val is stored in eax

ret
addValue ENDP

;--------For Sum Output Result----------

outputValue PROC

; output result

mov edx, OFFSET outputSumMsg ; Output text
call WriteString


mov eax, sum
call WriteInt ; prints the value in eax


ret
outputValue ENDP


exitLabel:
exit


END main
```

Comment: `PTR` is not an instruction and obviously 64 bits don't fit in 32 bits. The sum of two 32-bit numbers is only 33 bits though, and the extra bit is in the carry flag.

Comment: i can use 2 reg of 32bit and give 64bit value but i dont have idea how to use it...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `CF` (carry flag) to determine if there was some overflow when adding two integers. Addition carry of two `n-bit` wide integers can never be greater than one bit, but note that you can do this only when talking about unsigned addition. Signed addition with 64-bit result needs two 64-bit integers.

Here is example of unsigned 32-bit addition resulting to one-bit carry.

```
mov eax, (1<<31)|1 ;set Most-Significant Bit (MSB) to 1, what will surely cause overflow
mov ebx, (1<<31)|1
add eax, ebx
jc .go             ;we need another bytes for our carry
```

signed version:

```
;let eax and ebx be the numbers we want to add
cdq   ;expand 4-byte integer to 8-byte integer <-- this won't affect real value of EAX
xchg eax, ebx  ;cdq has fixed operands, change eax with ebx
xchg edx, ecx  ;... and edx with ecx
cdq   ;do the same for number that was in EBX

add eax, ebx
adc edx, ecx   ;that 'c' on the end is important, it will add 
               ;the carry flag to the result so possible overflow will be handled
;Result is now in EDX:EAX
```